# Custom page controll with words instead of dots - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, uipagecontrol

I am currently making a timetable in a collectionView.
I want the user to scroll through the weeks using paging in the collectionView.

I am struggling to change the dots into words like: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday. IS this possible using page controll, or should I code from scratch? See image for example

[image]

Comment: Definitely not using page control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this pods, I think it will help you.

https://github.com/rechsteiner/Parchment

Parchment is a very flexible paging view controller. It let’s you page between view controllers while showing any type of generic indicator that scrolls along with the content. Here are some benefits of using Parchment:

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

XLPagerTabStrip is a Container View Controller that allows us to switch easily among a collection of view controllers. Pan gesture can be used to move on to next or previous view controller. It shows a interactive indicator of the current, previous, next child view controllers.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help i will try it out! Looks like what i just needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it custom components. It's easy to implement.

Take UICollectionView to this paging options. And add UITableView below to UICollectionView.

Change your data after select any item in UICollectionView.